# Good lecture notes or books on field theory/mechanism in gravitational field?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, resource-recommendations, education, qft-in-curved-spacetime

In gravitational field, the things are usually different from those in flat spacetime. For instance, sometimes you have to use covariant derivative $\nabla$ instead of ordinary differential $\partial$, or one may find the volume element is $d^4x \sqrt{g}$, not $d^4x$, ect.

I am looking for notes/book having very detailed and friendly discussion on these stuff. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Basically you need a book on differential geometry

Comment: *" very detailed and friendly*" Ain't that the dream?

Answer (score 1):

The question is too broad to get an answer, which is expected and desired. If the question is about how to grasp the understanding the notations and mathematics behind the general relativity - the good and rather easy introduction is Nakahara's book - "Geometry, Topology and Physics" [https://www.amazon.com/Geometry-Topology-Physics-Graduate-Student/dp/0750306068](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0750306068), also a good reference is Eric Poisson's book - "Relativist's toolkit" https://ru.scribd.com/doc/310295327/Relativist-s-Toolkit. Also I would recommend Wald's "General Relativity".